# AADSTS50058 when calling AAD causes refresh loops

Tags: angularjs, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api, adal.js

sometimes i'm getting error AADSTS50058 when calling Azure Active Directory Graph API from Angular.

my setup :

- adal-angular 1.0.13
- angular v1.5.8
- google chrome with no flag on 'Block 3rd party cookies'
- tried with KMSI flag on
- no extensions that block cookies on Chrome (latest)
- **update** : route package "angular-route"

this is the code:

```
var my_endpoints = {
    'https ://graph.windows.net/': 'https ://graph.windows.net/'
};

adalProvider.init({
    instance: 'https ://login.microsoftonline.com/',
    tenant: "common",
    clientId: '[my-client-ID-here]',
    extraQueryParameter: 'nux=1',
    cacheLocation: 'sessionStorage',
    endpoints: my_endpoints 
}, $httpProvider);
```

n.b.: https links are without space, i set this because of stackoverflow.

this is the error i can't resolve : 
error AADSTS50058: A silent sign-in request was sent but no user is signed in. The cookies used to represent the user's session were not sent in the request to Azure AD. This can happen if the user is using Internet Explorer or Edge, and the web app sending the silent sign-in request is in different IE security zone than the Azure AD endpoint (login.microsoftonline.com).

tried to disconnect and re-login but no success

the awkward thing i can't figure out is that it often works, then sometimes it raises this error, keeping the page in reload loop.
if i erase the AAD calls it works as expected.

is this because i have to manage 2 tokens, one with the API and one with AAD GraphAPI?

if yes, how can i manage this ?

any help is highly appreciated

Comment: I don't know whether you can fix this. I have experienced this in the Azure Portal when it redirects to Application Insights Analytics. The reason was that corp IT had configured login.microsoftonline.com as a Trusted Site in Internet Explorer, and the AppInsights site was not. That apparently stops IE from allowing silent sign-on. My fix on my PC was to add the other site to the trusted sites list also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think i have found the issue;
in google chrome, in a stress-test, immediately after login, i set the "Save the password" browser pop-up to "Never" when the browser asked me;
in canary and other browsers, where i set "Save" or simply ignored, the problem never appeared.

seems the issue was fixed after clearing the "never saved" password list.

checkbox "Use Smart Lock for Passwords to remember passwords for apps and sites" or "Offer to save your web passwords" is irrelevant, tested checked state and non-checked.

thank you !

Answer (score 3):

According to your description, it seems that you are facing an infinite loop issue at random. There are multiple reasons may raise this issue.

First you may check whether you are using `ui-router`, if so, please check whether you have set the stage definition for root page "/". Add this to your state provider routing:

```
 $stateProvider.state("/", {
        url: "/",
        templateUrl: "<could be home page or default page>",
        requireADLogin: true,
    });
```

Also, there may be some other reasons occur this issue, like **Nested iframe creation**, **Hash reset**. You can refer to https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js/wiki/FAQs#q2-my-app-gets-into-an-infinite-loop-sometimes-leading-to-digest-iterations-error for more info.

Furthermore, you can add the code below to `app.js` to turn on logging. Implement the log method depending on how you want to redirect logs.

```
Logging = {
    level: 3,
    log: function (message) {
        console.log(message);
    }
};
```

Also, you can see all the info including error description in seesion storage leveraging Chrome Developer Tools:

[image]